# adding to a class using a loop

Tags: java, class, loops

I'm working on a project at the moment that involves reading data from a text file and storing it as a new Class. In order to get it all done easily, I figured it best to use a while loop like the following:

```js
while (text.hasNextLine()) {
  System.out.print("Please enter class name: ");
  tempName = kb.next();
  //sort text into parts for the class
  Class (tempName?) = new Class();
}
```

kb is the Scanner, tempName is a String variable.

Would a code like that work? I figured I can't just go "Class name = new Class" because each time the loop ran, it would overwrite the previous data, where-as I need to store all the data. It would be better if I could just get it to go "Class name(x) = new Class" where x is an int variable that increases each time the loop runs, but I'm not sure if that would work either.

If it wouldn't work, an alternative way to do this would be appreciated. I'm also not sure how to validate the Class name so that data isn't accidentally overwritten.

**Please note:** I can't use ArrayList, as the project's instructions forbids "dynamic data structures such as arraylists", so basic Java code is all I am allowed to use.

**EDIT:** Here's one of the classes I have to use.

```js
public class Customer_16997761 {

  private int customerID;
  private String surname;
  private String firstname;
  private String address;
  private String suburb;
  private int postcode;
  
  //Bunch of get methods
  
}
```

The text file I have has a bunch of lines with those variables listed in that order. I need to read the line, split it into the parts, store it as a new Customer, then rinse and repeat until the end of the file.

Comment: It would help to know what you ARE allowed to use, or more instructions? What is the verbiage used by the instructions on what the code must do?

Comment: I don't think you are using Class as intended. Class describes an object. You seem to be trying to define instances of objects as classes. Try to tell us what you want to do without using any java terms/keywords, or tell us exactly what you were asked to do?

Comment: I'm using Class as intended, I just didn't name the Class in question.

Comment: The code has to read from a text file (Jobs.txt for example) and store it in the class (Jobs).

Answer (score 0):

Your solution will not work however as an alternative you could just create a new java file on each iteration and in the file you could put the text for class definition. So you could name the file tempname.java and in the file put public class tempname{}. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

As I can't imagine any project/assignment would call for allowing an end user to decide on the names of variables, I'm going to answer the question under an assumption: The project wants the Class() you create to have a field called "name" and let the user manipulate it.

```
public class Foo() {
    String name;
    //other stuff

    //Contstructor makes it easy

    Foo(String _name) {
        name = _name;
    }
}
```

Then in your code you can do:
    int counter = 0;

```
while (text.hasNextLine()) {
  ++counter;
}

Foo[] myFoos;
myFoos = new Foo[counter];
```

Start the read over:

```
int i = 0;
while(text.hasNextLine()) {
    System.out.print("Please enter class name: ");
    tempName = kb.next();
   //sort text into parts for the class
   Foo[i] = new Foo(tempName);
   ++i;
}
```

There are more efficient ways of doing it, depending on how you want to get the number of lines in the file, when and what you want to do stuff with those lines, and the method you want to use for the second read. But, this should give you an idea of how to compose your custom solution.

Comment: Not quite but close enough that this helps a lot. I wasn't sure if you could start a read over, but knowing that helps.

Comment: If you can read once, you can read as many times as you want. But it may involve closing the file and reopening, or creating a new scanner for the 2nd read. Also, if you're storing a unique customerID in the class, the class var name should NOT have to be unique. If everything is stored in array, just do a for loop through the array, do the stuff when the `if(Customer[i].getID() == comparisonID) {//do stuff}` and don't forget to `break;` after the match.